# Can I use DirectShow in Web application?

Tags: web, directshow

I want to develop an online video website and I think it's good to use DirectShow to implement some functionalities of video processing on that site. So my question is that can DirectShow be used on web application like the video website I just mentioned?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, using ActiveX in Internet Explorer. But that's ugly and deprecated way.

HTML5 have access to webcams, so, are you sure that DirectShow is required?

Comment: I don't use webcams. I want to use Directshow Editing Services to do some kind of video editing on my website. I used it before and it worked well on my desktop application.

Comment: I think only ActiveX is possible here. Or you can check Windows UWP usage that have DES-like technology (I'm starting using it now and have everything except SMPTE transitions, but, maybe, doesn't find it yet.). Maybe UWP code usage is possible. But that's just an idea.

Comment: I googled UMP and found that it's only used for Windows 10, but my platform is Windows 7, so I don't think it's suitable for me.